# Error processing Timeseries tensorflow notebook on TPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

Here's a Timeseries notebook I used from the good work by [Magnus Erik Hvass Pedersen](http://www.hvass-labs.org/) - thanks for that:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F6CuGVWN5TNgIjqxdu5glFeGBEr71TgO

I have had success running a version of this notebook via Google Colab on a GPU but when I do the same (after some modifications to make the code compatible on TPUs) I get this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input to have shape (299776, 20) but got array with shape (33309, 20)`

The full stack trace can be found on the cell location https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F6CuGVWN5TNgIjqxdu5glFeGBEr71TgO#scrollTo=wdSmXdvDw5HL.

It has been a bit of a tug-of-war to get the input/output data shapes in order but as we kept solving I/O shape issues other shape related issues started proping up.

The notebook is available for sharing and commenting.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the initial query has been resolved by changing test set size to a smaller number ie 1344, see https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F6CuGVWN5TNgIjqxdu5glFeGBEr71TgO#scrollTo=6u0JTx3Zw5Fn&line=2&uniqifier=1 among other changes to the notebook.

Now I get the error `AssertionError: batch_size must be divisible by strategy.num_towers (1 vs 8)`, `batch_size` has been set to 256 which is divisible by 8, so the error message isn't clear. See section **Train the Recurrent Neural Network** from the ToC on the left-hand panel.
--
This isn't ideal I'd like to use all the data.

Comment: Hi Mani! you should edit the question to reflect your update issue if you feel like it is similar enough to the original question.

Comment: @d_kennetz The title of the query does reflect the issue, the temporary resolution leads to a new problem, so we didn't really solve the original problem (if you see my comment above), I would like to drop the work-around and get the notebook to work.

Comment: batch_generator is yield'ing within the for loop, where in the original notebook its yielding after the for loop. I think that might be the issue?

Comment: @michaelb are you saying this after running the notebook and looking at the code or just DRY run of the code. I will take a look and see if I can use your hint - thanks for that.

Comment: Actually it seems the batch_generator was not the issue, I was able to get the model to train by removing the validation_data option. This makes sense as the validation data for this model is just one example, not a batch. I'll see if there is a way around this and follow up.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, did you undo all our steps, if you see we got around the first problem by adjusting the test set to 1344, see cell https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F6CuGVWN5TNgIjqxdu5glFeGBEr71TgO#scrollTo=6u0JTx3Zw5Fn&line=2&uniqifier=1 and the next one

Comment: When I reset the test dataset to its original code state, remove the validation set and re-run the notebook, I get *ValueError: Operation 'tpu_140099307695464/VarIsInitializedOp' has been marked as not fetchable.*

Comment: @michaelb Two questions for you, what code changes did you make to get the notebook work on TPUs and also did you get a chance to find out how to make the original notebook run without any errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the error `ValueError: Operation 'tpu_140099307695464/VarIsInitializedOp'`.
Try using `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer` instead of using RMSProp from `tensorflow.keras.optimizers`.

Comment: Thanks again, it worked, the model is now training - no errors so far.

Comment: Here's the link to the tweet and post talking about the notebooks - https://twitter.com/theNeomatrix369/status/1065939282265808896, thanks both @michaelb and Aman2930 for your help. You guys also helped to make this possible.

Comment: Since this fixed your issue, would you mind choosing this as the correct answer for the benefit of future users?